# obtain a js variable from an ajaxed page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My question is this, if I have a page say index.HTML that has some script in, something simple like...

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    Var buttonBox = {};
})
</script>
```

Obviously there would need to be more, I'm trying to make this simple.
Then I use ajax to retrieve some data from the db and fill in the contents of a div, but in my return page I have another script tag, something like...

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function() {
    buttonBox.start = "some variable or string";
})
</script>
```

Along with the HTML content. Why is buttonBox.start not available in the main index.HTML page? Is there a way to make it available? Is formatting the output of my server page as a huge json object then parsing through it to set every needed variable along with the HTML content the best/only way to achieve this?

Thank you for the help, if you need more info I'll be happy to provide it, I was just minifying this for sake of ease.

Comment: Your `buttonBox` variable is not visible because it's hidden inside the jQuery callback function. If you want it to be visible across the entire page, it will need to have wider scope than that.

Comment: @andrewdotnich If I were to set that variable outside the $(document).ready(function({}) would that make it usable to the ajaxed pages?

Comment: Yes, it would, but you'd need to access it via `window`, the way @the_ajp 's answer does to make sure it's really the variable you wanted…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could add the buttonBox to the window and make it `global`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     window.buttonBox = {};
});

$(function() {
    window.buttonBox.start = "some variable or string";
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing this, just wasn't sure if it was good practice or not. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for each function in each  tag, if the function is not global, it can not be reused. to make a function become global, you should use window. Also, you can put this function into an external file and load with